# How can i get the number of bytes allocated by mmap?

Tags: c

I'm building a custom implementation of `malloc` using mmap.

If the user wants to allocate 500 bytes of memory, i call `mmap(0, 500, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED | MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0)`. `mmap` returns a pointer to a block with size 4096 (if that is the page size).

In my linked list I want to have one block set to 500 bytes marked as taken, and one block set to 4096-500=3596 bytes marked as free. It is not clear, however how much memory `mmap` really allocates. How can I get that information?

Comment: I do not think this is a good approach. You should allocate chunks bigger than 4k. Otherwise, you will end up with a lot of chunks too small for anything. You also need to take into account overhead of `mmap` and maximum number of mapped regions.

Answer (score 1):

The prototype of `mmap()` is:

```
void *mmap(void *addr, size_t length, int prot, int flags, int fd, off_t offset);`
```

Technically you are guaranteed only that it will allocate `length` bytes. However, in practice it allocates whole pages (i.e. multiples of `PAGE_SIZE`) though you are not guaranteed you can use anything beyond `length`. Indeed per the man page:

> `offset` must be a multiple of the page size as returned by `sysconf(_SC_PAGE_SIZE)`.

Note that there is no restriction on `length` being a multiple of `PAGE_SIZE` but you might as well round up `length` to a multiple of `PAGE_SIZE` (as that's what's going to be allocated anyway), in which case the amount of memory allocated is exactly `length`. If you don't do that, it will allocate the minimum number of whole pages that contain `length` bytes.

Comment: "though you are not guaranteed you can use anything beyond `length`" That's not correct, you can always use the whole page.

Comment: @PerJohansson - see http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/mmap.html - *"The address range starting at `pa` and continuing for `len` bytes will be legitimate for the possible (not necessarily current) address space of the process. The range of bytes starting at `off` and continuing for `len` bytes will be legitimate for the possible (not necessarily current) offsets in the file or shared memory object represented by `fildes`."*

Comment: Also *"Thus, while the argument `len` need not meet a size or alignment constraint, the implementation will include, in any mapping operation, any partial page specified by the range `[pa, pa + len)`."*

Comment: The problem is that if i dont put all the page into the linked list, there will be "grey" areas in heap that have unclear purposes. If one grey area is surrounded by two free blocks, and you want to merge them inot one free block, would you include the grey area or not?

Comment: You cannot use pages that are not `mmap`'d in. These are not grey areas, these cannot be used and will probably `SEGV`. Arguably, the partial page at the end of the block is a grey area, though my reading of the standard is that you can't use that either.